# Safari and Terminal eating up too much battery

Tags: terminal, safari, battery, monterey

I am using MacBook Pro M1 and have started noticing recently that Safari and Terminal were eating up a lot of battery. I don't know since when it began, maybe after updating on macOS Monterey. To check this I opened activity monitor and found that Safari was showing 15.72 under `12 hr Power` and Terminal was showing 22.53. All though `Energy Impact` was altering. Also I found out that Safari was showing `Intel` under `Kind` column in CPU section even though I am using M1. I am attaching screenshot for the same. Please help me if someone knows how to fix it.

[image]

[image]